# How to find all the integer pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation $x^{17}+6 x^{14}+2 x^{5}=y !+2 $

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

We are going to solve the equation
$$x^{17}+6 x^{14}+2 x^{5}=y !+2 \tag*{(*)}$$
by the  Fermat Little Theorem:
$$x^3\equiv x \quad  \pmod 3 \quad \forall x\in Z.$$
Assume that $y \geqslant 3$.

Applying the  Fermat Little Theorem to  $(*)$  in modulo $3$ yields

$$x^{5} \equiv x^3\cdot  x ^2\equiv x^3 \equiv x$$

$$x^{17} \equiv\left(x^{5}\right)^{3} \cdot x^2  \equiv x^{3}\cdot x^2\equiv x\\y !=0 $$
Expressing the equation $(*)$ in modulo $3$ yields
$$ x+0+ 2x\equiv 2 \quad(\bmod 3) \\ 0\equiv 2 \quad(\bmod 3) $$
which is a contradiction.
$$\boxed{ \textrm{There is no such integer pairs for }y\geqslant 3.}$$

---

Now let’s check for the integer pairs
$(x,y)$ for $y=0,1,2$.

When $y=2$,
$$0 \equiv x+0+2x\equiv 2!+2 \equiv 1   \pmod 3,  $$
which is a contradiction.

$\therefore$ there is no such integer solution.

---

When $y=0,1$, $(*)$ becomes
$$f(x)=x^{17}+6 x^{14}+2 x^{5}-3=0$$
because $f(-1)=0$ but $f(1) \neq 0$ and $f(\pm 3) \neq 0$

$\therefore x=-1$ is the ONLY integer solution.

---

Now we can conclude that the integer pairs $(x, y)$ satisfying $(*)$ are only $(-1,0)$ and $(-1,1)$.

***My Question***

Is there simpler solutions?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: RHS is even. So $x$ must be even. let $x = 2m$. We have $2^6m^5(1 + 3.2^9m^9 + 2^{11}m^{12}) = y! + 2$. But $2^6 \nmid RHS$. This leaves negative $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You could also note that $y!+2 \pmod 8 \in \{2,4\}$ for any $y \ge 2$, which is even, so $x$ must be even. But then the RHS would be a multiple of $x^5$ and thus as $2|x^5$, a multiple of $32$. So then the RHS $x^{17}+6x^{14}+2^{x^5}$ must be $0 \pmod{8}$ $\not \in \{2,4\}$....